# Future task attached to a different loop

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi, motordriver, motorengine

I am trying to connect to mongodb in FastAPI. I am repeatedly getting this exception.

File - main.py

```
app = FastAPI(
    title=config.PROJECT_NAME, docs_url="/api/docs", openapi_url="/api"
)

@app.get("/api/testing")
async def testit():
    user_collection = readernetwork_db.get_collection("user_collection")
    all_users = await user_collection.find_one({"email": "sample_email"})
    print("all users --- ", all_users)
    return all_users

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", reload=True, port=8888)
```

File - session.py

```
import motor.motor_asyncio
from app.core import config


print("here we go again....")
client = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient(
    config.MONGOATLAS_DATABASE_URI)
readernetwork_db = client.get_database("readernetwork")
```

Exception -:

```
all_users = await user_collection.find_one({"email": "sample_email"})

RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-4' coro=<RequestResponseCycle.run_asgi() running at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py:389> cb=[set.discard()]> got Future <Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/futures.py:360]> attached to a different loop
```

I don't know where I am getting this wrong. Should I specify a event loop to motor?

Answer (score 10):

You can have `mongodb motor` client in the global scope, but creating and closing it should be done inside an async function. The most preferable way of doing that in `startup` and `shutdown` handler of the application. Like so:

```
# mongodb.py
from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient


db_client: AsyncIOMotorClient = None


async def get_db_client() -> AsyncIOMotorClient:
    """Return database client instance."""
    return db_client


async def connect_db():
    """Create database connection."""
    global db_client
    db_client = AsyncIOMotorClient(DB_URL)

async def close_db():
    """Close database connection."""
    db_client.close()
```

```
# main.py
app = FastAPI(title=PROJECT_NAME)
...
app.add_event_handler("startup", connect_db)
app.add_event_handler("shutdown", close_db)
```

Note that you need the line `global db_client` to modify the global variable defined beforehand.

Comment: Maybe I should ask a new question, but I find this problem to come back when I use `fastapi`, `motor` and `fastapi-users` since `fastapi-users` requires something like ```user_db = MongoDBUserDatabase(UserDB, db["users"])```.  How can we setup `user_db` in the `app.add_event_handler` lines?

Comment: This was super helpful. We had a file that initialized a MongoDB connection (using `motor`, via ODMantic) at the package level. Putting the initialization in an `async` function - and then calling that function to retrieve a database connection - fixed our issue. Thank you, [@alex_noname](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13782669/alex-noname).

Comment: This was very helpful. One note - declaring db_client globally in any file didn't play nicely on my system (I'd get "None has no method get_database()") - instead, just combining connect_db and get_db into one function did the trick: ```async def get_db_client() -> AsyncIOMotorClient:
    """Return database client instance."""
    db_client = AsyncIOMotorClient(settings.MONGO_URI)
    return db_client```

Comment: @duma Can you share an example of how did you accomplish that? I'm on the same scenario.

Comment: "You can have mongodb motor client in the global scope, but creating and closing it should be done inside an async function" 
Where does this claim come from ?

Comment: @AndréCosta, at the global scope for the file, we have `_engine: Optional[AIOEngine] = None`. Then we have this function: `async def get_engine() -> AIOEngine:`. In this function, we do `global engine` and then check `if _engine`. If that passes, it's returned. Otherwise, it's created and returned. We also have a function called `set_engine_connection(conn: str, db: str):` that allows overriding the current `_engine` to be connected to a test database (which is then called when bootstrapping integration tests).

Answer (score 2):

Without the need for using global...
You can access the application state from the request given to any route.

```
#main.py
async def open_db() -> AsyncIOMotorClient:
    app.state.mongodb = AsyncIOMotorClient(DB_URL)

async def close_db():
    app.state.mongodb.close()

app.add_event_handler('startup', open_db)
app.add_event_handler('shutdown', close_db)
```

Within each request to a given route you will have access to the app state.
For example,

```
@app.route('/{username}')
async def index(request: Request, username: str):
    user = await request.app.state.mongodb['auth']['users'].find_one({"username" : username})
```

You can even make it easier by doing something like this in your open_db function. Specify a state value like 'users' to be a specific Collections instance.

```
async def open_db() -> AsyncIOMotorClient:
    app.state.mongodb = AsyncIOMotorClient(DB_URL)
    app.state.users = app.state.mongodb['auth']['users']
```

Now you can just do this,

```
@app.route('/{username}')
async def index(request: Request, username: str):
    user = await request.app.state.users.find_one({"username" : username})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
client = AsyncIOMotorClient()
client.get_io_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop
```

works for me.